# lidR readLAS function crashes R when reading some las files

Tags: r, crash, lidar, las, lidr

I have previously been using the lidR package and it was working great (highly recommend). However today I simply tried to open an airborne las file and the R sessions crashed. Here is the code, it ain't complicated.

```
library(lidR)
las = readLAS("E:/2018LiDAR/PointCloud/Block_03/tilecls/Noise_Processed/e1042n0792.las")
```

This crashes the R session, either in R or R studio (grey bomb). I have tried to open multiple airborne LiDAR las files from this same dataset and they all crash R. However, when I open much larger las files (100 times larger) from a different project they load into R just fine. I have updated my R version to 3.6.2, updated to the latest version of lidR, checked my filepaths, had the las file on my C drive, and on an external hard drive, doesn't matter. I have checked the las files in other programs such as PDQ viewer and ArcGIS and they look fine and perform fine in those software programs. And like I said everything was working fine yesterday.  Does anyone have any suggestions for what I could try and what is going wrong?

Comment: This is a bug in the [`rlas`](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/rlas) package that should be reported with a reproducible example (i.e. including a problematic file).

Comment: Thank you JRR, I will do that. I will report back and close this thread when I get the issue resolved.

Comment: I posted this issue in the lidR github. It looked like it was a bug specific to how windows 10 64 bit was reading the wkt in the las 1.4 file. It has been resolved for lidR version 2.2.4 - https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/issues/323